# DataTables Invalid JSON response

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm having some trouble with DataTables.

I'm trying to use the server-side script to make data loading faster in a project, but I keep getting errors.

When I load the page, the first error I get is:

```
datatables.min.js:86 Uncaught Error: DataTables warning: table id=lista_pedidos - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
at K (datatables.min.js:86)
at Object.error (datatables.min.js:48)
at i (jquery.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:2)
at A (jquery.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:4)
```

---

When I type anything on the search field I get the same error in the logs and in the tab "Network" I get the following error:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined offset: 0 in <b>C:\wamp64\www\prevmais\sistema\app\server\ssp.class.php</b> on line <b>116</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined offset: 0 in <b>C:\wamp64\www\prevmais\sistema\app\server\ssp.class.php</b> on line <b>162</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined offset: 1 in <b>C:\wamp64\www\prevmais\sistema\app\server\ssp.class.php</b> on line <b>162</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined offset: 0 in <b>C:\wamp64\www\prevmais\sistema\app\server\ssp.class.php</b> on line <b>176</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined offset: 1 in <b>C:\wamp64\www\prevmais\sistema\app\server\ssp.class.php</b> on line <b>176</b><br />
{"error":"An SQL error occurred: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 100' at line 5"}
```

---

These are my scripts:

**1) Initializing DataTables:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';

$('#lista_pedidos').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        url: "/app/server/server_side.php",
        dataType: 'JSON'
    }
});
```

**2) Server-side script:**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

/*
* DataTables example server-side processing script.
*
* Please note that this script is intentionally extremely simply to show how
* server-side processing can be implemented, and probably shouldn't be used as
* the basis for a large complex system. It is suitable for simple use cases as
* for learning.
*
* See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
* side processing requirements of DataTables.
*
* @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
*/

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* Easy set variables
*/

// DB table to use
$table = 'pedidos';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The db parameter represents the column name in the database, while the dt
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes

$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
array(
'db' => 'pedidos_data',
'dt' => 1,
'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
return date( 'jS M y', strtotime($d));
}
),
array( 'db' => 'pedidos_nome', 'dt' => 2 ),
array( 'db' => 'pedidos_cpf', 'dt' => 3 ),
array( 'db' => 'pedidos_rg', 'dt' => 4 ),
array( 'db' => 'pedidos_nascimento', 'dt' => 5 ),
array( 'db' => 'pedidos_status', 'dt' => 6 ),

);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
'user' => 'root',
'pass' => '',
'db' => 'prevmaisaude',
'host' => 'localhost'
);

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
* server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
*/

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*What am I doing wrong?*" a) you are not paying attention to the very clear   PHP error messages b) you are somehow confusing the script that is executed with another script you have posted here.  There is no line 116, 162 or 176 in the ssp.class.php above.

Comment: Hey @davidkonrad, I'm using the very file that comes with the download, its path is _(DataTables-1.10.15\examples\server_side\scripts\ssp.class.php)_. I think you're talking about the GitHub ssp.class.php, which doesn't have those lines for sure. But I've also tried to use it and still get the same errors, only in diferent lines.

Comment: Hey @user3339870, we need to see what is going on in C:\wamp64\www\prevmais\sistema\app\server\ssp.class.php ...To me it seems to be a really simple question of trying to access some none existing indexes in an array.

Comment: Hey @davidkonrad, It seems to be a none existing indexes for fure. But now I'm using this script [link]https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php which is the latest, I'm confused for I'm having trouble with DataTables scripts. I think it was suppose to work.